# How do I connect to a Heroku psql database using a connection string in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, node-postgres

I am attempting to connect to a Heroku database using a connection string.
I know the connection string is good since I use it successfully in another Heroku app to connect to the database, but when I run the block of code below:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    connectionString: 'connectionString',
});

client.connect();
```

I get the following error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry`

I've also tried the code below:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    connectionString: 'connectionString',
    ssl: true,
});

client.connect();
```

but this returned the error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: self signed certificate`

I would rather not enable
`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` if I can, since I plan on deploying this app to Heroku and would like it to be as secure as possible.

How do I connect to the database using the connection string?

Comment: It's fine to turn on that env flag for dev. Just don't flip it on in prod.

Comment: Your first error message is incomplete.  Looking at the rest of the message could help solve the problem.